# How to properly get a serializer instance in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, serialization, django-serializer

I'm trying to get an instance of a serializer in my overwritten list method and then pass it in through perform_create. Basically what this code does is it checks if the queryset is empty and if it is, we do a `perform_create`. The problem is that I'm trying to get an instance of the serializer so I can pass it in to the `perform_create` method. I don't believe the line `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)`
 correctly grabs the serializer as it shows nothing when I try to log it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
class ExampleViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
queryset = Example.objects.all()

serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwner)

def list(self, request):

    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
    # print(request.data)
    if name is not None:

        queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
        if (queryset.count() == 0):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            print(serializer)
            return self.perform_create(serializer)
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', queryset))
    elif name is None:
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', queryset))
```

Comment: This seem correct to me. Does `list` get called at all?

Comment: excuse my ignorance: do you expect the `list` method to be called on a `POST` request (create)? See [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#request-objects)

Comment: On the client side I am doing a get request with name as the query params. If the name cannot be found in the current queryset i want to do a perform_create. I know this is against REST framework but i need it for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, with

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
```

you are trying to access `POST` data while responding to a `GET` request.

DRF [ViewSets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) offer the methods:

- `list` (called upon an HTTP GET request)
- `create` (called upon an HTTP POST request)
- `retrieve` (called upon an HTTP GET request)
- `update` (called upon an HTTP PUT request)
- `partial_update` (called upon an HTTP PATCH request)
- `destroy` (called upon an HTTP DELETE request)

Also see [this explicit example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#binding-viewsets-to-urls-explicitly) binding HTTP verbs to ViewSet methods

So if

1. you are POSTing data, the `list` method isn't called at all (as suggested by @Ivan in the very first comment you got above).

The solution is to move the code to the appropriate method, i.e `create`

Otherwise

2. your client is GETting, the `list` method is called, but `request.data` will be empty at best.

The solution is to make the client provide the parameters for the creation as GET parameters,  along with `name`.

That way the view will find them in `self.request.query_params`

In case you have a form, simply change the way it sends its data by making it use HTTP GET. See [here for further info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

Comment: Hello, I have indicated what the problem can be, given the info provided. See my edit for the solutions